# Why does my OData return data contain "@odata.type"?

Tags: odata

I created a OData application locally.
and The Request address is "http://localhost:5182/odata/Users"

```
 [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUsers()
    {
        var result = userService.GetQueryable().ProjectTo<UserModel>();
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Now, if I ask ViewModel, the returned data will contain "@OData.type"
Like This:

```
{
"@odata.context": "http://localhost:5182/odata/$metadata#Users/MyApp.WebApiOData.Models.UserModel",
"value": [
    {
        "@odata.type": "#MyApp.WebApiOData.Models.UserModel",
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "admin",
        "PhoneNumber": null
    },
    {
        "@odata.type": "#MyApp.WebApiOData.Models.UserModel",
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "mapley",
        "PhoneNumber": null
    }
```

}

if I'm not asking for ViewModel,The returned data will Like This:

```
{
"@odata.context": "http://localhost:5182/odata/$metadata#Users",
"value": [
    {
        "Name": "admin",
        "Pwd": "123456",
        "RealName": null,
        "Sex": null,...
```

I don't want to return the result to include "@OData.type", and the Url address contains "MyApp.WebApiOData.Models",I just need the json for myapp.

How can I solve this problem?
The OData information in this area is too small, and my English is not good.
And I don't understand the "@odata.type" usedfor.

If you can give me a little help, I will be indebted forever.

Answer (score 1):

odata.type is the namespace.typename of your requesting resource, to remove this in response add the header in request can resolve this:

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, queryUrl);
request.Headers.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json;odata.metadata=none"));                  
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
```